# Getting one date less

Tags: ios, date

I don't why i'm getting one date less, when I'm converting a string from a date, i'm getting one date less, e.g. when i'm converting 18/06/2014, i'm getting 2014-06-17, Any idea why this problem, my codes are:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"18/06/2014"];
```

This is what I'm getting wholly from the log: `2014-06-17 20:00:00 +0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to take the timezone into account. Your current timezone seems to be ahead of GMT. If you print the entire date with say a time stamp, then you will get the difference. So i suggest you add the timezone to the NSDateFormatter

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"18/06/2014"];

    NSLog(@"Date : %@", date);
```

Comment: this is what I'm getting wholly: 2014-06-17 20:00:00 +0000

Comment: did you try the above code?

Comment: your timezone differs by how many hours from GMT